# How do I update and then select the updated row

Tags: java, sql, queue

I have a table that has values ID and STATE. I want to update an individual item that has state 0 and set its state to 1 and then get its ID so that it can be processed. There would be several threads doing this, so I would need to have only one thread update the state and process the ID.

Basically, I'm trying to avoid using a message queue.  Is this possible to do just using SQL?  I basically have a java app that will be inserting and fetching these items.  I just want to implement a sort of queueing mechanism without using a queue server.

Comment: If you are updating a table dont you need the ID to do so? in that case you already have the ID

Comment: yes, you are right, i guess what i would do is select 1 where state = 0 then update it, but i don't want 2 threads to work on the same one.

Answer (score 1):

If your ID is, for example, 1234, then you would need to have your app do this to the database:

```
update MyTable set State = 0 where ID = 1234
```

then:

```
select State, other_field_1, other_field_2, other_field_N 
from MyTable where ID = 1234
```

There is no way in SQL to both update a record and select the updated record in one step.